# Problema ao exibir conteúdo e alterar a visualização

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estava com um problema referente a como passar os dados para o front e mudar a visualização de tais informações, após dar uma pesquisada, juntei algumas coisas que fui pesquisando, ficou bem simples, mas funcionou de inicio (errei nessa parte, não testei com mais conteúdo).

O código, recebe os valores do back e apenas exibe true ou null (exibe nada rs):

```
{{#each qrs}}
<h2 class="d-inline" id="horarioDaAula1">{{horario1}}</h2>
    <h2 class="d-inline" id="horarioDaAula2">{{horario2}}</h2>
    <h2 class="d-inline" id="horarioDaAula3">{{horario3}}</h2>
    <h2 class="d-inline" id="horarioDaAula4">{{horario4}}</h2>
    <h2 class="d-inline" id="horarioDaAula5">{{horario5}}</h2>
    <br>
{{/each}}
```

O script que utilizei para fazer a alteração da visualização, para ficar mais bonito de certa forma.

```
<script>
      // Pegar o valor e exibir ícones. Para colocar na visualização da presença do aluno
    for(i = 1; i<=5; i++){

      var n = "#horarioDaAula";
      var horario = n + i;

      var myElement = $(horario);
      var myText = myElement.text();  
      if(myText == "true"){
        myElement.html('<i class="fas fa-check-circle fa-xs" style="color: green"></i>');
      }else{
        myElement.html('<i class="fas fa-times-circle fa-xs" style="color: red"></i>');
      }
    }

  </script>
```

Até ai estava tudo tranquilo, mas quando o {{#each qrs}} foi implementado, mais valores aparecem de acordo com cada collection. Com isso ficou como a imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não tenho muito conhecimento, sou novato, pelo que percebi (creio eu) o jquery pega somente um ID e não todos os h2 que possuem o mesmo ID.

Como eu poderia estar arrumando essa questão, ou fazendo de outra forma?

**EDIT 1**: Como aparece no front com a utilização do {{#each qrs}}

```
    <h2 class="aa d-inline" id="horarioDaAula1">true</h2>
    <h2 class="aa d-inline" id="horarioDaAula2">true</h2>
    <h2 class="aa d-inline" id="horarioDaAula3">true</h2>
    <h2 class="aa d-inline" id="horarioDaAula4">true</h2>
    <h2 class="aa d-inline" id="horarioDaAula5">true</h2>
<br>
    <h2 class="aa d-inline" id="horarioDaAula1">true</h2>
    <h2 class="aa d-inline" id="horarioDaAula2">true</h2>
    <h2 class="aa d-inline" id="horarioDaAula3">true</h2>
    <h2 class="aa d-inline" id="horarioDaAula4">true</h2>
    <h2 class="aa d-inline" id="horarioDaAula5">true</h2>
<br>
```

Ou seja, quanto mais documentos (mongodb) eu tiver, mais aparece o h2.

Tentei pegar os valores do h2 pela class (aa) mas não consegui pegar esses valores

A forma que tentei pegar pela class:

```
for(i = 1; i<=5; i++){

      var n = ".aa";
      var myElement = $(n);
      var myText = myElement.text();  
      console.log(myText)

      if(myText == "true"){
        myElement.html('<i class="fas fa-check-circle fa-xs" style="color: green"></i>');
      }else{
        myElement.html('<i class="fas fa-times-circle fa-xs" style="color: red"></i>');
      }
    }
```

Comment: Não entendi, qual é o problema?

Comment: O problema é que observe na imagem, os valores que eram todos true na primeira linha, foram mudados para icones, mas na segunda não acontece o mesmo.

Comment: O id é uma identificação única. Não pode haver repetições. Se houver dois elementos com o mesmo id o javascript pode identificar somente 1. No seu caso você disse que tentou pegar pela classe aa. Como você fez? o seletor para classes é o (.) em vez de (#).

Comment: vou dar um exemplo mais ou menos de como ficaria, e te mando

Comment: A forma que tentei pegar os conteudos pela class editei a pergunta.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dfsb387r/1/

Comment: Olha ai, o que acontece que quando você usa o seletor de classe, você seleciona mais de um elemento de uma vez. Usei uma função chamada ``each`` do jquery que passa por todos os elementos que foram selecionados.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Se eu compreendi bem essa questão do jquery, o `$(this).text()` simplesmente recebe o conteúdo e também pode estar passando outro conteúdo?

Comment: O this se refere ao elemento html selecionado. Quando você joga ele dentro da função jquery($) é para que se consiga utilizar as funções do jquery com ele. Essa função text é uma das funções do jquery.

Comment: Quando você passa desse jeito ``$(this).text()`` ele retorna o conteúdo do texto do elemento. Porém se você passar algum texto no parametro dessa função ele substitui o texto do elemento html ``$(this).text('modifica o texto do elemento')``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solução incorreta:

Se eu entendi, você está fazendo um ***"foreach" em "qrs"*** e pra cada ***qr*** você está usando o código que colou no script.

Então, tente a seguinte solução (Eu não testei, estou fazendo de cabeça)
***Laço qrs***:

```
{{#each qrs}}
    <h2 class="aa d-inline" data-id="1">{{horario1}}</h2>
    <h2 class="aa d-inline" data-id="2">{{horario2}}</h2>
    <h2 class="aa d-inline" data-id="3">{{horario3}}</h2>
    <h2 class="aa d-inline" data-id="4">{{horario4}}</h2>
    <h2 class="aa d-inline" data-id="5">{{horario5}}</h2>
    <br>
{{/each}}
```

***Script:***

```
<script>
      // Pegar o valor e exibir ícones. Para colocar na visualização da presença do aluno
    for(i = 1; i<=5; i++){

      var myElement = $(`.aa[data-id="${i}"]`);
      var myText = myElement.text();  
      if(myText == "true"){
        myElement.html('<i class="fas fa-check-circle fa-xs" style="color: green"></i>');
      }else{
        myElement.html('<i class="fas fa-times-circle fa-xs" style="color: red"></i>');
      }
    }

  </script>
```

---

### O problema:

Mesmo com essa solução, acontece que sempre os data-ids vão ser reiniciados na sua aplicação, ou seja, depois do 5, sempre volta a ser 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 e o javascript vai entender que é pra pegar todos os data-ids 1, 2... novamente.

Além disso, o seu laço só está englobando os 5 primeiros elementos, se houverem mais, ele não vai fazer a troca

---

### Solução correta:

1. Coloque todos os elementos do horario em uma variável:

```
var Horarios = $('.aa');
```

2. Faça um laço de repetição com todos os horários da tela

```
Horarios.each(function(index, item) {

});
```

3. Verifique se o conteúdo de cada item do laço de repetição (de cada horário) é true ou false, se true, imprime o ícone de presente, se false, o ícone de falta.

```
  let myText = $(this).html();
    if(myText == "true"){
      $(this).html('ICONE PRESENTE');
    } else {
      $(this).html('ICONE FALTOU');
    }
```

4. Código completo:

```
<script>
    // Coloca todos os horarios em uma variavel
    var Horarios = $('.aa');

    // Percorre o array criado na varivel anterior
    Horarios.each(function(index, item) {
      // Verifica se o html dentro do horario tem true ou false
      let myText = $(this).html();
        if(myText == "true"){
          $(this).html('ICONE PRESENTE');
        } else {
          $(this).html('ICONE FALTOU');
        }
    });
</script>
```

***Demonstração:***

```js
var Horarios = $('.aa');

Horarios.each(function(index, item) {
  let myText = $(this).html();
    if(myText == "true"){
      $(this).html('<span style="color: green">&#10004;</span>');
    } else {
      $(this).html('<span style="color: red">&times;</span>');
    }
});
```

```css
/* deixa os h1 em uma unica linha */
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="aa">true</h1>
<h1 class="aa">false</h1>
<h1 class="aa">true</h1>
<h1 class="aa">true</h1>
<h1 class="aa">true</h1>
<h1 class="aa">true</h1>
<h1 class="aa">false</h1>
<h1 class="aa">true</h1>
<h1 class="aa">true</h1>
<h1 class="aa">true</h1>
```